# U-boot compiler error

Tags: linux, compiler-errors, u-boot

I am new to u-boot.When I compile the u-boot,I get the following error:

```
root@tl-virtual-machine:/home/tl/Desktop/uboot# make CROSS_COMPILE=arm-fsl-
linux-gnueabi- -j4
CHK     include/config/uboot.release
CHK     include/generated/timestamp_autogenerated.h
UPD     include/generated/timestamp_autogenerated.h
CHK     include/generated/version_autogenerated.h
UPD     include/generated/version_autogenerated.h
HOSTCC  tools/dumpimage.o
HOSTCC  tools/image-host.o
HOSTCC  tools/mkenvimage.o
HOSTCC  tools/mkimage.o
HOSTLD  tools/mkenvimage
HOSTLD  tools/dumpimage
HOSTLD  tools/mkimage
CC      arch/arm/cpu/armv7/am33xx/clock_am43xx.o
AS      arch/arm/cpu/armv7/start.o
arch/arm/cpu/armv7/am33xx/clock_am43xx.c: In function 
'rtc_only_enable_basic_clocks':
arch/arm/cpu/armv7/am33xx/clock_am43xx.c:142:13: internal compiler error: in 
decode_addr_const, at varasm.c:2632
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <http://gcc.gnu.org/bugs.html> for instructions.
make[1]: *** [arch/arm/cpu/armv7/am33xx/clock_am43xx.o] Error 1
make: *** [arch/arm/cpu/armv7/am33xx] Error 2
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
CC      common/main.o
CC      common/board_f.o
CC      common/cmd_version.o
LD      common/built-in.o
root@tl-virtual-machine:/home/tl/Desktop/uboot#
```

How can I specify the compiler in u-boot.I have configured the CROSS_COMPILE variable in Makefile as follows:

```
CROSS_COMPILE =/home/tl/Desktop/opt/Embedsky/gcc-4.6.2-glibc-2.13-linaro-
multilib-2011.12/tq-linaro-toolchain/bin
```

Thanks for your help,Light

Comment: Did you read the section titled "Building the Software:" in the **README** file in the source code?  *"How can I specify the compiler ..."* -- Just make sure that its `bin/` directory is first in your PATH environment variable.

Comment: Hello,Sawdust.Thanks for your help.
I specify the toolchain in the `/etc/profile`.And the `bin/` path is set first in `/etc/profile`.But the command line report the same error.When I change the toolchain to arm-linux-gnueabihf- 4.7version,it works.But I need to use toolchain arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi- to build the uboot in order to match with other parts of the project.Does the toolchain arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi- cannot work well with the uboot version?Or Do I miss some important configures?
Thank you for helpping,Light

Comment: You are specifying the cross toolchain correctly.  However, whatever toolchain you found has a problem and itself is failing.  I would recommend using one of the Linaro toolchains or one of the Free Electrons toolchains.  Or, go back to your vendor for support.